# Application insights to a wcf servcie

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure my winforms application to call a wcf service.
Since the error happens on the azure hosted wcf service I am hoping application insights can help me.

```
      These are the steps I followed
        An official link from Microsoft on how to add Application Insights to a Windows Forms application. From the link:

        In Azure - portal.azure.com

        Create an Application Resource. ::New / Developer Services / Application Insights.
        Notice the instrumentation key generated, grab a copy and set it aside, we'll need it when we configure your application.
        In Your Application

        NuGet - Add 'Application Insights API'

    <ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">
        <TelemetryChannel>
            <DeveloperMode>false</DeveloperMode>
        </TelemetryChannel>
        <TelemetryModules>
            <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
        </TelemetryModules>
        <InstrumentationKey>**

your-instrumentation-key-guid**</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

I guess here is where I am lost. The service is invoked from a winforms application. The endpoint for the WCF service lives in the app.config of the winforms client. How does this end point know to use application insights.
I also need https?

Working Log for AfterReceiveRequest

      
        1df55aaa-0208-4a6f-820b-fb7efc12484d
        
          
            2019-03-13T14:54:53.344Z
            2019-03-13T14:59:53.344Z
          
          
            user
            password
          
        
        https://workingVMerver/Services/2019/Image.svc
        http://test.com/ws/DocImgSrch

Non working Log:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="8047fce6-2567-4cbb-b3d9-a0ece3e9199c" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">d9377396-bdd0-48d7-b9a5-d1b6e2ff8a85</ActivityId>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2019-03-13T13:54:47.899Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2019-03-13T13:59:47.899Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-f0319ed1-aac2-4768-9d1c-e1dec7598bf1-1">
        <o:Username>userr</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://nonworkingvmv1/Services/2019/Image.svc</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://jackhenry.com/ws/DocImgSrch</Action>
</s:Header>
```

Both are https requests but in the non working one SSL doesn't get recognized and header throws a fault

```
   <binding name="httpsCertificateBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
          openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
           <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
             <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
             <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
           </security>
        </binding>

    <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="Services.Image">    
         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpCertificateBinding" name="BasicHttpEndPoint" contract="Services.Interfaces.IImage" />

            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsCertificateBinding"  bindingNamespace="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008" contract="Services.Interfaces.IImage" />

           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
          </service>

 <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <PfRequestOutputBehaviorExtensionElement/>
         <serviceCredentials>
             <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Services.CustomMembershipProvider,Services"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
         <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />

         </behavior>
```

Its the same behaviors.. but ssl doesn't work on the faulty one. Validator doesn't get called. And the service throws an error that cant understand mustunderstand=1

The only difference in the request is this
In the faulty one. Even though I call https the URL here is taking http
   http://nonworkingVm/Services/2019/Image.svc

In the working one its https
  https://workingvm/Services/2019/Image.svc

SSL is handled at the gateway level. Azure application gateway redirects http request to https. All I am doing is set up the WCF config on the VM to specify https bindings. I am not "requiring ssl" on the iis. The URl to the nonworking is https but the WSDl says http. I don't know why it would say this even after configuring all the bindings. I have never worked with azure.

I also tried ValidateMustUnderstand=false. This makes it throw an exception that

```
 Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. 
This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.  
This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security
```

The response with validate setting turned off looks like this. Obviously there is not action must understand header

```
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="d2fbd200-01e1-4657-b35a-b583be38341a" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
```

Comment: I haven't used application insight to troubleshoot application problems. It's like a tool to collect application data metrics and improve application performance with http/https traffic. What problems do you encounter? If you can tell me the wrong information, I will give you some advice.

Comment: So you own / have access to the WCF service source code?  It'd be worth sharing the code of the function that's giving you problems.  How are you calling the WCF service?  What error handling do you have?  Share the code for that.  If what you have done is add application insights to the **win forms** app, then you're not going to get much information.

Comment: @Brend Green: I own the service. I am creating a proxy using channel factory. The end point is in the app.config. I am missing something. Like you said, I added insights to the winforms app. Also updated the key from the portal. What else do I  need to do? Please be patient. I am not very good at this

Comment: @Abraham Qian: Updated my question to figure out the problem. Validator does not get called.